# What is bootstrap 4 media breakpoint up down and between?

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4, breakpoints

Can somebody explain me what is `media-breakpoint-up`, `media-breakpoint-down`, `media-breakpoint-between`, and `media-breakpoint-only` in Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 0):

These are related to css media queries. They are used to set breakpoints when the page size is changed from desktop, to tablet, to mobile sizes.

Here is a great resource for all the details: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/